# Where to set displayed data vs plotted data in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I am looking for a setting in Highcharts/stock that would allow me to apply a different format to displayed values of data, but not to the actual data as it is loaded into the series data.  For example, we would like to plot y-axis data with precision up to 16 significant digits, and likewise, time values that use 6-8 sig figs.  But that's not the precision we would like displayed in the tooltips, or other labels.  However I am unable to find a way to format it without affecting both what is plotted and what is displayed.  Here is an example of why this is a problem: let's say we have data points taken at .0001234s, .0001244s, .0001254s, and .0001264s, but we want to format the display of the time to ".0001" for all 4 data points.  If we format it, then the "plotted" data ends up looking like it occurred at the same time-stamp, thus producing a stair-step look to our waveform.

I have looked at the custom functions that I can create to override tooltip display, but it doesn't appear that there is an easy way to make that very generic so that I can apply to all of the various chart instantiations (we use lots of different chart types), and that only covers tooltips; X-axis labels and Y-axis labels would also need separate functions for overriding those display values; there's possibly other places I haven't thought where the display might be affected as well.  Is there any single, centralized place where the data points display value or format can be changed?

Example of stair-step appearance:
[image: Example of stair-step]

TIA

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display various numbers (axis labels, tooltip, etc.) with various number of decimal places, you can use `Highcharts.numberFormat` function.

API Reference:
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts#numberFormat

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/eg0vepgq/

Comment: Hi d_paul, thx for the suggestion, but this still means I have to write custom code for every tooltip, xlabel and ylabel formatter on every chart. Since default formatting for tooltips can change dep. on chartType, I would have to reproduce that formatting in many places, which is what I'm trying to avoid. I also can't use numberFormat b'c we have specific requirements about significant digits and this method only addresses decimal places - I have my own sigFigFormatter, that's not the issue, I just want to set it at the same time I am setting my x/y values, which is done in just one place.